# Windows Azure VM Filezilla FTP Setup

Tags: windows, azure, virtual, filezilla

I am using Windows 2012 R2 VM machine in Azure. I have read multiple article to setup Filezilla server in this environment. However, I am not successful. Any one faced this issue? Any solution will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Setup FTP on Azure VM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422391/how-to-setup-ftp-on-azure-vm)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order to gain maximum from the community, please do your homework first and search for the answers yourself before really posting it!

Comment: How to Setup FTP on Azure VM describes the steps for IIS. Unfortunately I couldnt find the correct solution for Filezilla server.

Answer (score 1):

Just remember to add Filezilla to Windows Firewall :-)

Answer (score 0):

I'm dealing with the same thing right now. locally the FTP serv works great. remote I cannot establish a passive connection. Based on my research this is because Azure is not set up for Passive-FTP. I am uncertain if we can get FileZilla to operate in a active-FTP mode. Will post back if I ever get to the bottom of it. Mine currently connects and authenticates but 'cannot retrieve directory listing' when it tries to kick over to passive (transfer) mode.

Comment: so how things going?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the Virtual Machine endpoints are open, be sure to also add the appropriate Windows Firewall rules if you have Windows Firewall enabled on your Windows VM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, We can connect to Azure server via FileZilla Client.
Steps:

```
Login to Azure portal: https://portal.azure.com
Click on App Services.
Select the Site and then click on Get publish profile.

Save the file and open it in notepad.exe.
The file contains 2 <publishProfile> sections. One is for Web Deploy and another for FTP. 
Under the <publishProfile> section for FTP make a note of the following values: 
    publishUrl (hostname only)
    userName --------------------------> This is the information you are looking for 
    userPWD
```

Add the PublishUrl to Hostname, Username and password in their respective fields.

Connected.

The link will give the detailed description of the steps flow with images.

[Here is the link.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/kaushal/2014/08/01/microsoft-azure-web-site-connect-to-your-site-via-ftp-and-uploaddownload-files/)

Thanks