# Does Azure have a way through REST API for getting a file from a VM?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

Looking at [Operations on Virtual Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/reference/jj157206(v=azure.100)), I see that there are many management tasks that I can do through the REST API. Is there any way I can stream a file, e.g. something like `"GET/{filePath}"` where  `{filePath}` is like `d:\stuff\somefile.txt` or `\\somenetworkpath\foo\bar.html`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No there is no direct way to get a file Path from Azure VM through REST API**.

*It's also not a secure manner to provide file Path using REST API*

If you really want to access the File from outside the VM. You need to configure the **[FTP/SFTP for your file Path in Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18713618/7073340)**. This way it will be a secure way to access your files.

But remember that you will not get the filepath`(d:\stuff\somefile.txt)` using this. You will get access to the file(s) alone which is more likely as `\\somenetworkpath\foo\bar.html`