# How do I set up FTP access to Azure App Service?

Tags: azure, ftp, azure-web-app-service

I've used Visual Studio to "publish" my website to Azure.

It seems to be working OK. Now I would like to be able to FTP files up to this App Service.

But how do I set up my FTP credentials within this App Service so I can authenticate via FTP?

I was expecting to see an option called "Deployment Credentials" under the "Deployment" area but there simply isn't an option called "Deployment Credentials".

Also, if I click the "Deployment Center" option under "Deployment" I just get a blank part of the screen on the right hand side of the screen.  This suggests something should be returned but nothing is.

What am I missing? How do I set up an FTP username and password?

Clarification:
I can see how to access the preconfigured ftp username/password. My question was about how to CREATE a new user/password combination.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Setup FTP on Azure VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18422391/how-to-setup-ftp-on-azure-vm)

Comment: @Alfredo Mark is asking about App Service not Virtual Machines

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: I think before marking a question down it might be a good idea to understand it.

Answer (score 62):

In the Azure Portal:

1. click on your App Service that you'd like to access from FTP.
2. On the Overview tab for your App Service, look at the top navigation bar and click on the "Get Publish Profile" link. This will download your publish profile.
3. Open the downloaded publish profile (it's a text file). Your FTP credentials are there.

**Edit 6-21-2022: A Better Way**

To get your FTP credentials, now you can do the following:

1. Go to your Azure Web App in the Azure Portal
2. Click on the Deployment Center menu item under the Deployment heading in the left-hand nav.
3. Choose the FTPS Credentials tab. Your FTP endpoint, username, and pass are available to copy.

Comment: Thank you Rob.  This gives me access to the built in username and password.  I was trying to find out how to CREATE a new user/password combination.

Comment: @MarkChallice On the FTPS Credentials tab, you can regenerate a new SFTP password, but not a new username for Application Scope.

Comment: Would using Filezilla with the credentials in Azure Portal, enable me to connect and manually upload files to my App Service? Seems this is the case? I keep copy/pasting into Filezilla and I've yet to find a combination that works.

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe you can use multiple methods to publish to an App Service. I think it's limited to one. However, you are not locked into that one upon creation as you can change it from `Deployment Center`. Thus, you can't both publish your app from Visual Studio and FTP upload your app.

However, if you want to FTP for other reasons, you can piggyback on the ability to FTP for diagnostics logging. If you click, `Diagnostics logs` under `Monitoring`, you will find your FTP URL for your App Service and the user name needed for FTP. This leaves one issue as you need to setup a password for FTP. If you go to `Deployment Center > Deployment Credentials > User Credentials`, you should be able to update your password for the App Service FTP server. Thus, you'd be able to access your App Service from FTP.

For more information, you can check out [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-deploy-ftp) from Azure.

Comment: Thank you Technogeek.  It does seem possible to use two separate methods to update the site (publish and FTP).  I've done it today.

Whether it's a good thing to do that is a different question!

An example where it is probably the least worst solution is if I use publish to push the whole site up but I want to change certain settings in the web.config used on the Azure server.  There isn't a concept of a dev web.config and a live web.config in VS publish so I made the changes to the web.config manually then FTP'd the amended web.config up to Azure

Comment: Ah, for that, I have used the Kudu SCM applicaiton. It's available at
`https://<your_app_name>.scm.azurewebsites.net`. I use the Debug Console with PowerShell and the file explorer to edit the files I need to change. I've done this quite frequently without issue. Though you may have to restart the App Service depending on the changes you're making.