# Azure Web App Service use "Get Publish Profile" username and password to link FTP not work

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I followed this page [How do I set up FTP access to Azure App Service?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53173754/how-do-i-set-up-ftp-access-to-azure-app-service/53174333)

And I used portal user name like:
[image]

and `Get Publish Profile`
[image]

and used its `userPWD` value
[image]

I tried to type FTP hostname to windows 10 explore bar and system show error:

> FTP does not encrpt or encode passwords or data before sending them to the server. To protect the security of your passwords and data, use WebDAV instead.

[image]

Comment: Just to confirm if you want to connect to Azure Web App via FTP to upload or download files? If so you need to have a FTP client (like FileZilla or WinSCP etc.) to connect to the Server.
Check this blog link might be helpful: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-deployment-types-and-ftp-credential-types/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [SnehaAgrawal-MSFT](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10893879/snehaagrawal-msft). Posting your suggestions as answer to help other community members.

When you are trying to connect to Azure Web App via FTP to upload or download files you need to have FTP client to connect to the server.
Need to have FTP URL, Username and Password for connecting to our App Service via FTP Client.
Below Screenshot will help you in getting FTP details by navigating to the settings pane.

[image]

As suggested check the [FTP Client](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-app-service-deployment-types-and-ftp-credential-types/) link for further information.